# How to unzip a multitude of .gz files with windows command prompt

Tags: windows-10, command-line, archiving

I have a system that must accept and send data 24/7, and runs 3 instances of itself on 3 different virtual machines (nicknamed _1, _2, _3 for later use). In the logs the timestamp of the traffic is in the microseconds, which means that any given second can only be assembled by extracting information from logs from all 3 servers.

Now to the task at hand: I need a command prompt to:

1. extract all .gz files - All I need is a command that will successfully unpack every .gz in the given folder, see why down below
2. find a certain timestamp and if found, extract that information into a new file - i need some polishing advice here, see below
3. merge all files into one based on timestamp
4. delete all files that are 0 bytes

An example of the archive's original name: gw.2023-02-21-1.log.gz
On the 3 instances you will find an archive with this name, so I simply download the archives with two additional characters, as a way to determine which instance is the source. To simplyfy, all the downloaded archives will look like this:
gw.YYYY-MM-DD-S.log_1.gz -> so the _1 tells me that it's from instance 1, and there will be the same for _2 and _3. Luckily the file's extension will also be renamed, so there's no way to overwrite when we extract all.

1. so the tar command gives me the cold shoulder with the "unrecognized archive format" error (tried the `tar -xvzf *locationOFarchive* -C *locationTOextract*`). I'd like for a solution that extracts all the .gz in a given folder into the same folder.
2. the command I use is this:
   `@find "timestamp" < source file > target file`
   the problem is that I have like 60+ lines of this, because I must define all the source files and target files. Can this be done in a simpler way, like
   find "timestamp" in all .log* files and IF there's a hit, write it in a file?
3. i don't even know how to begin...
4. this is solved

Comment: If you are going to go down this path, I suggest installing WSL so the commands aren't foreign or ports.  At that point, the problem becomes nothing to do with windows.

Comment: thank you, but sadly i must do this on my workplace computer, so I can't install anything. There were a lot of hits about the tar command, some even said that it's especially for zip and gz but it doesn't work.

Comment: I would try 7zip then.  It doesn't even need to be installed (especially the command line version).  The only annoyance for me with 7zip is that tgz/tar.gz is a two pass operation.  It is worth a shot.